# (Java) Java cannot find my Image File

Tags: java, directory

I am new to Java.

My Problem is that my Java program cannot find the image file im trying to use as
a JButton. (Currently this code does nothing, as I am simply getting a desirable look
first).
**THIS IS MY MAIN CLASS**

Code:

```
package mainClasses;
/*
 * Frame Info and all that shit,
 * mainFrame is the actual frame itself
 * it will refer to MainC.java a lot Main class = Main Class
 */
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;

import resources.ResourcesManager; 

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "serial" })
public class mainFrame extends JFrame {

ResourcesManager rManager = new ResourcesManager();


public mainFrame() {
    JButton playButton = new JButton(rManager.pButton);
    JButton infoButton = new JButton();
    JButton exitButton = new JButton();


    int x = 310, y = 300;
    setSize(x, y);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(null);
    setTitle("Kingdom Raider");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    /*Buttons and Properties*/
                        /*X,  Y,  X, Y*/
     playButton.setBounds(10, 10, 70, 40);
    /* Add if problem cannot be sorted */ // playButton.setText("Play");



    add(playButton);

     infoButton.setBounds(90, 10, 110, 40);
     infoButton.setText("Information");
    add(infoButton);

     exitButton.setBounds(210, 10, 70, 40);
     exitButton.setText("Exit");
    add(exitButton);

    //This is for checking if the file is here.
    File imageCheck = new File("/JavaGame/src/resources/playButton.png");

    if(imageCheck.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("File found!");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    }

    repaint();



}









public void Painting (Graphics g) {


}
}
```

**THIS IS MY RESOURCESMANAGER.JAVA**

```
package resources;

import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ResourcesManager {

/*Here, your going to want to declare anything
 * needed.
 */

public ImageIcon KRLogo = new ImageIcon("/JavaGame/src/resources/kingdomraiderlogo.png");
public ImageIcon pButton = new ImageIcon("/JavaGame/src/resources/playButton.png");

public void settings() { //Set the stuff settings, locations e.t.c.
    //BLAH

}

}
```

So basically the Button needs pButton from the ResourcesManager

Which is Practically playButton.png which is located in the resources package,
the same folder as the ResourcesManager.java

Please Help me with my directory issues.

EDIT: SORRY FORGOT, NO ERROR, JUST A BLANK BUTTON COMES UP WITHOUT MY IMAGE.

As for my directory it looks like

```
src

mainClasses (package)
   mainFrame.java
   runClass.java
resources (package)
   kingdomraiderlogo.png
   playButton.png (image wanted at the momment.)
   ResourcesManager.java
```

I'll +1

Comment: Are you looking where Java is looking? To find that out, check the result of: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: Prefer using `ClassLoader` for load stream or files.

Comment: 1) A lot of code posted, while the problem is located in one line of code (the ImageIcon construction) 2) the essential information is missing (the absolute location of the file, and your classpath) 3) the I'll +1 remark sounds like we should be grateful if you give us a +1 ... you should be grateful when there is an answer worth giving a +1

Comment: @Robin Give him a break, it's one of his first Q's. You're not wrong about too much info (although many new users don't put enough), but you could be more polite and welcoming.

Comment: @weston Yeah, it sounds more harsh then I intended. Should have found a more polite/constructive way to communicate this message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
public ImageIcon KRLogo = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
(ResourcesManager.class.getResource("/resources/kingdomraiderlogo.png"))));

public ImageIcon pButton = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
(ResourcesManager.class.getResource("/resources/playButton.png"))));
```

Edit:

In Java you have two ways of accessing files. One way is via the path that uses forward slashes, which is usually used in the `getResource()` method of the class `Class`. The first slash referc to the src folder of your project.

Second way is a `pathname` and is used in the constructor of the class `File`, for example. On windows, this then uses double backslashes, because a backslash has to be escaped. Problem is the platform independency, which is easily regained by using `File.Separator` in the pathname String.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the path as absolute (leading /).  Is that supposed to be a relative path or do you really have a JavaGame/src/resources/... folder off of your root drive?

Comment: I dont know, i just used Copy Qualified Name in Eclipse and Pasted into the Brackets.